# What's the significance of specifying a file mode when reopening STDOUT to /dev/null?

Tags: ruby, io-redirection, dev-null

I'm reading an example ruby script that creates a daemon by forking, creating a new session, forking again, then redirecting stdin, stdout, stderr to /dev/null

Here's a snippet of the redirection:

```
STDIN.reopen '/dev/null'
STDOUT.reopen '/dev/null', 'a'
STDERR.reopen '/dev/null', 'a'
```

What's the significance of specifying the file mode (`'a'`) in this case? Would the behavior be any different, for example, with

```
STDOUT.reopen '/dev/null', 'w'
```

or even

```
STDOUT.reopen '/dev/null'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular significance, but it's semantically helpful to a reader who would expect that `STDOUT` is `append` or `write`, but not `read`. It's also defensive against the default (typically `read`) changing in the future, unlikely as that may be. In fact Ruby has protections against changing the mode of `STDIN` or `STDOUT`.

```
STDOUT.reopen '/dev/null', 'r'

test.rb:1:in `reopen': <STDOUT> can't change access mode from "w" to "r" (ArgumentError)
from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

This does work on other IOs though, and it's always nice to be explicit.

```
f = File.open('file.out', 'w')
f.puts 'Hi'
f.close

f.reopen('file.out', 'r')
puts f.read
```

```
$ ruby test.rb
Hi
```